# Parsing Json object with multiple array and add to a list

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting this as a web response from server and i want to parse it and add it to a list

```
{
    "Id": [
        "7",
        "8",
        "9"
    ],
    "Title": [
        "Title 1",
        "Title 2",
        "Title 3"
    ],
    "Description": [
        "desc1",
        "desc2",
        "desc3"
    ],
    "NewsUpdatedDateTime": [
        "2010-02-26T10:40:30",
        "2010-02-27T10:40:30",
        "2010-02-28T10:40:30"
    ],
    "ImageUrl": [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
    ],
    "LastUpdatedTime": "2010-02-28T10:40:30",
    "ResponseMessage": "Data retrieved successfully",
    "ResponseCode": "1"
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: So what is the problem??

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for JSON Parsing...

I create sample code for your JSON data.. Check and let me know is it working?

```
String jsonData = your_data;
ArrayList<String> mListID;
ArrayList<String> mListTitle;

try {
JSONObject jsonOBJ = new JSONObject(jsonData);

// Getting JSON Array node
JSONArray mArrayID  =  jsonObj.getJSONArray("ID");
mListID = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0 ; i<mArrayId.length(); i++)
{
    mListID.add(mArrayId.get(i))
}
JSONArray mArrayTitle  =  jsonObj.getJSONArray("Title");
mListTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int j=0 ; j<mArrayTitle.length(); j++)
{
    mListTitle.add(mArrayTitle.get(j))
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  //your json String
  String jsonStr;

  if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

        // Getting JSON Array node
        JSONArray data  =  jsonObj.getJSONArray("ID");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

You should read some tutorials and documentation on json parsing in android from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html), [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

```
  You can implement it like this :



    List id;
    List title;
    String jsonTxt = inputStream;
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonTxt);
    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObj.optJSONArray("Id");
    JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObj.optJSONArray("Title");
    if (jsonArray1.length() > 0) {
    id=new ArrayList();
    for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray1.length(); index++) {
    JSONObject sellerObj = jsonArray1.optJSONObject(index);
    id.add(sellerObj.optString("name"));//name of ids 
    }
   }
```

saee as Title or other array.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you parse you server response

```
json jsonResponse = new json(response);

JSONArray id[] = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("Id");

JSONArray title = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("Title");

JSONArray description[] = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("Description");

JSONArray newsUpdatedDateTime[] = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("NewsUpdatedDateTime");

JSONArray imageUrl[] = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("ImageUrl");

String lastUpdateTime =  jsonResponse.getString("LastUpdatedTime");

String responseMessage =  jsonResponse.getString("ResponseMessage");

String responseCode =  jsonResponse.getString("ResponseCode");
```

//==========================================================================//

Then you can parse remain your single array:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < id.length(); i++) {  // **line 2**
     String name = id.get(i);
    }
```

I think it will help.